# Directx9 Vertex colour blending not working on AMD GPU's

Tags: directx, game-engine, game-development, amd-gpu

We have noticed a rather strange issue related to AMD and vertex colour blending, For some reason when a vertex is rendered on AMD GPUs for us seem to be unable to blend the colours for the vertices.

```cpp
void gradient_rect(vec3i pos, vec3i size, colour top_left, colour top_right, colour bottom_left, colour bottom_right, float rounding = 0.f) override{
  c_vertex verts[4] = {
    {vec4(pos.x, pos.y, 0.f, 0.f),                   top_left.tohex()},
    {vec4(pos.x + size.x, pos.y, 0.f, 0.f),          top_right.tohex()},
    {vec4(pos.x, pos.y + size.y, 0.f, 0.f),          bottom_left.tohex()},
    {vec4(pos.x + size.x, pos.y + size.y, 0.f, 0.f), bottom_right.tohex()},
  };

  for(u32 i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    add_vert(verts[i], D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP);

  flush_to_gpu(current_primitive_type);
}
```

Our system works by creating a vertex buffer shared between the GPU and mapped to the client, we push vertices into this buffer and then flush them off to the GPU.

We assumed it was something related to our batching system, so we ended up just calling `DrawPrimitiveUP` manually and had the exact same result, It seems that some specific `RenderState` flag could be responsible for this behavior, and we just don't have the expertise or knowledge to tell exactly why this behavior is occurring.

We had a tester dump his entire `RenderState` so we could compare it between our development machines `RenderState`s, and we noticed no real differences that could cause any issues.

To prove that we know this is related specifically to AMD GPUs, we had two other people confirm that this was happening exclusively with AMD GPUs, we also had one of these people swap their AMD GPU out with a NVIDIA GPU and the problem went away.

This is what a correctly blended vertex should look like:

[image]

This is what a incorrectly blended vertex looks like on AMD GPUs:

[image]

We have considerable reason to suspect that the root of this problem is related to a `RenderState` that is incorrectly set to work with AMD GPUs

For anyone that is wondering, here is our `RenderState` that is set before rendering is started:

```cpp
// texture related
device->SetPixelShader(nullptr);
device->SetVertexShader(nullptr);
device->SetTexture(0, nullptr);
device->SetFVF(D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE);
device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_MULTISAMPLEANTIALIAS, false);
device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRGBWRITEENABLE, false);
device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_NONE);
device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, false);
device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA);
device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, true );
device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SCISSORTESTENABLE, true );

// colour related
device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_COLORWRITEENABLE, 0xFFFFFFFF);
device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_MODULATE);
device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG2, D3DTA_DIFFUSE);
device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_MODULATE);
device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG2, D3DTA_DIFFUSE);

device->SetStreamSource(0, vertex_buffer, 0, sizeof(c_vertex));
```

Comment: Since you are using the legacy "fixed-function' pipeline (rather than programmable shaders), you should closely look at the various Direct3D 9 caps bits for the two cases. It's likely the AMD driver is just not reporting support for something you are assuming is always there. DxCapsViewer can dump out all caps information so you can have your customer send you the output of that tool. See [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/DxCapsViewer/releases).

Comment: Note this "weirdly missing caps" issue was rampant in the days of Direct3D 8 and Direct3D 9. It was one of the main motivations for the [Direct3D Hardware Feature levels](https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-feature-levels/) design used in modern DirectX 11 / DirectX 12.